# kafka-streams split into branches and merge them back throws TopologyException: Invalid topology: Processor is already added

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Trying to use the "new" (at least for me) `split` method/API to branch stream into a few parts (instead of the deprecated `branch` method.

I have 3 conditions to split my stream. On every branch, I need to perform some transformation and finally merge all 3 back into one stream.

```
var split = mystream.split(Named.as("branch-"));
        split
        .branch(
            (k, wrapper) -> condition1,
            Branched.withFunction(ks -> ks, "name1")
        ).branch(
            (k, wrapper) -> condition1,
            Branched.withFunction(ks -> ks, "name2")
        ).branch(
            (k, v) -> condition3,
            Branched.withFunction(ks -> ks, "name3")
        );
        var branches = split.noDefaultBranch();

        var merged = branches.get("branch-name1").mapValues(p -> convertToAnotherObj(anotherObj))
        .merge(branches.get("branch-name2").mapValues(p -> convertToAnotherObj(anotherObj))
        .merge(branches.get("branch-name3").mapValues(p -> convertToAnotherObj(anotherObj)));
        
        merged.to(kafkaProps.getOutputTopic(), Produced.with(Serdes.String(), expSerde));
```

So, as I mentioned, I get an exception:
`kafka-streams split into branches and merge them back throws TopologyException: Invalid topology: Processor "branch-" is already added.`

I am looking into JavaDoc of streams `org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.BranchedKStream` and example from here:

```java
 Map<String, KStream<String, String>> branches = source.split(Named.as("split-"))  
    .branch((key, value) -> value == null, Branched.withFunction(s -> s.mapValues(v->"NULL"), "null")      
.defaultBranch(Branched.as("non-null"));    

KStream<String, String> merged = branches.get("split-non-null").merge(branches.get("split-null"));
```

The question is, if I can split, to perform some transformation on branches and merge all this back?

Appreciate it if anyone can point out where is my mistake.